# Embedded authentication + LDAP user verification in Django. How to?

Tags: python, django, authentication, ldap

#### Intro

- Django version: 1.10
- Python version: 3.5.2

I'm trying to implement an authentication based on a *LDAP* condition and I can't get my head around on how to achieve this.

My project already uses Django's built-in authentication system, which works great and looks like this:

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views
from coffee_app.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('coffee_app.urls')),

    url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}, name='logout'),
]
```

```
# forms.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django import forms


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=32,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'name': 'username'
                               }))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=20,
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                                   'class': 'form-control',
                                   'name': 'password'
                               }))
```

```
<!--login.html (relevant part)-->

<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" id="contact_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ form.username.label_tag }}</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    {{ form.username }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >{{ form.password.label_tag }}</label>
            <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    {{ form.password }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <br>
                <button value="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >
                LOG IN
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/>
</form>
```

---

#### Problem

Now, what I'm trying to do, is to verify whether a user exists in LDAP or not, before getting to the initial Django auth:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM

server = Server('server here', get_info=ALL, use_ssl=True)
conn = Connection(server,
                  user='DOMAIN\\username',
                  password='password',
                  authentication=NTLM)

print(conn.bind())
```

If `conn.bind()` returns `True`, I'd like to go further to Django's built-in authentication system and authenticate the user. Unfortunately, I don't know where / how to add this step in order to achieve this.

Some views look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url="login/")
def home(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")

@login_required(login_url="login/")
def activity_report_page(request):
    return render(request, "activity_report.html")
...
```

And their urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'report$', views.activity_report_page, name='activity_report')
]
```

---

Could someone please point out where should I add the *LDAP* piece of code so that I can first verify if a user exist there?

*PS: I didn't consider using `django-auth-ldap` because I don't really need a pure LDAP authentication-based system. Just a simple verification.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [customize authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/), where you more specifically want to [write an authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). I assume that your project is called 'coffee_site', and you have the app 'coffee_app'. You first want to change `coffee_site/settings.py`, and append `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['coffee_site.auth.LDAP']` to it. After this, you want to make and edit `coffee_site/auth.py`. As you said in the question you want to use the default authentication, and so you should inherit from `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`, you then want to make it so that if `conn.bind()` is not True, then you don't use the default authentication, and so you should return `None`. This can be implemented with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM

server = Server('server here', get_info=ALL, use_ssl=True)


class LDAP(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = kwargs.get('username')
        password = kwargs.get('password')
        if username is None or password is None:
            return None
        conn = Connection(server,
                          user='DOMAIN\\{}'.format(username),
                          password=password,
                          authentication=NTLM)
        if not conn.bind():
            return None
        return super().authenticate(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

**Note**: I checked this works on Django's side, but I made no effort to check that the LDAP code works.

Comment: I just tested this and it almost works the way I want, but not quite. If the user doesn't exist in DB (like added by me in the admin panel) it doesn't work. (E.g: I have user x in LDAP and in Django DB -> it logs in (it's not ok - it should work if the user is not in DB); I have user x in LDAP, but I don't have it in Django DB -> it doesn't log in (it should). Any ideas ?